# My external monitor randomly flickers for between a one and five seconds. Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, screen, flicker

I am a very yellow guy when it comes to linux so please, explain in to me like I am five.

My external monitor is MSI MAG301 CR2, although the resolution and quality are on point it just **randomly flickers for periods of 0.5-10 seconds. Time between them varies from just a couple of seconds to dozen of minutes. The time between them heavily depends on software used**, for example programming python rarely (or even not at all) gives any while using internet browser seems to make them appear the most. My Ubuntu release is 22.04.2. Graphics is GeForce GT 720M and the kernel is 5.19.0.38.39.

I will gladly answer any questions.

P.S The monitor is capable of 120 Hz while all i can use is only 60 (there is not even an option to change it). Could you also help me on that?
Thank You.

Comment: You have a video issue so you need to edit the question with the critical details. What Video card and drivers and kernel being used?

Comment: GeForce GT 720M, the kernel is 5.19.0.38.39. How do I check the drivers?

Comment: That info as I said needs to be added to the question with edit not as a comment.